# Add Quick Launch to a Page Layout

Tags: branding

I am trying to figure out how I can add the quick launch (for navigation) into the design of a page layout.

I am using the starter master page for publishing made by Randy Drisgill.

http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/releases/view/41533

I found out early on that you should not get rid of that :). So I added it back in and it 'works' ok but shows up on the left of all of my page layouts. I would like to display it within only certain page layouts.

Now while I know you can hide it using CSS, but that's not what I am trying to do. I just want it show up in a specific spot in my page layout.

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1):

^ Disregard the first, I think I misread your question. The answer in this link may help you instead: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/gu-IN/sharepoint2010customization/thread/5faea89f-f3ea-4b4b-b4c0-2c0cc7e6ceee

Comment: Thanks Guys ... I should of posted back with what I did. I have since found about content placeholders and how you put everything you need in the master page. Then on your page layouts, you can add an empty place holder so the original does not show. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Fooling around with the SharePoint masterpage is a delicate matter if you don't understand its structure. Thus trying to remove the Quicklaunch from the masterpage is not a good idea.

What I can recommend you do is to hide the quicklaunch with some CSS, and then on the pages that you actually want it to appear you insert preferably a HTML Form Web Part in which you insert some CSS to make it appear again. And if you want it to be placed any other place than its original place use some javascript to move it to the position of your choice.